# Last element in Backbone collection add / reset?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

How do you know if a model is the last one in the batch?

```
   // inside view    
collection = new ObjectCollection();
this.listenTo(collection, 'add', added);

added: function(mod){
    //if(mod.position.last)
}

collection.add([{'name': 'Human'}, {'name': 'Cat'}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at

```
added: function(mod){
    if (this.collection.at(this.collection.length-1) == mod) {
      //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`last`](http://underscorejs.org/#last) function from underscore that is also available in [Backbone's collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods):

```
added: function(mod){
    if(mod == this.collection.last()){
         ...       
    }
}
```

You can try it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myrk4pxe/)